# WebSocket error using restcomm and olympus on Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, restcomm

Trying to use the Olympus(WebRTC) application on the restcomm service/image in AWS.

The restcomm pieces all seem to work fine.  But when I go to http://myAWSIP:8080/olympus/#/ and try to login bob or alice, I get the following:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://myAWSIP:5082/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: It can be many things, your WS server can be down, your port 5082 is filtered or closed, your program is not managing ws connections properly, etc. Make sure the WS server is running and try it locally from the AWS server, if it works you will know it's a firewall problem.

Answer (score 2):

Right, as Javier noted, this seems like a connectivity issue. Please try the following:

- Check the AWS security group for your instance and make sure TCP 5082 port is open
- Login via SSH to your instance and check if Restcomm is indeed listening for TCP connections at port 5082:

  $ sudo netstat -anp | grep 5082
- If the above all look fine, then please collect restcomm logs (RESTCOMM_DIR/standalone/log/server.log) and paste them somewhere so that I can have a better look

Best regards,
Antonis

Comment: Thanks, opening up 5082 did the trick.  I was assuming everything would be set up, given the AWS image is meant for this application.  Bad assumption.

Comment: What version of AMI are you using?

Comment: centOS-6.5-x86_64-TelScale-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-no-lce-7.2.0.841.1-1e59d01f-c1b5-495a-8777-003c4527860e-ami-8c5fd2e4.2 (ami-2652db4e)

Comment: I believe this has been fixed in latest versions, could you try with 7.3?

Comment: It works with 7.3.  5082 is open when I start the image.

Comment: I think my other Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866096/restcomm-cloud-throwing-err-connection-timed-out-when-connecting-via-wss-mydom is also related to this.  But just wondering I can get help with my Question  please...thanks in advance